# What is the order of list if sort by date/time in APEX?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a list of objects I am querying and I am sorting it by start__c field which is a Date/Time type.

```
List<Notification__c> notifs = [SELECT id FROM Notification__c  
                  WHERE Read__c=false ORDER BY Start__c DESC];
```

When the Date/Time field is different it is working as expected displaying in the descending order.
But if the start__c is same for all Notification list,it is displaying in an unordered list.

What is the order in that case?

Comment: Well, the list is ordered, it just that ordering is not consistent because the field you are ordering on has same value. You can order by 2 different fields. First by `Start__c` and then by something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply extend the `order by` to include additional fields (in a hierarchy format) such as:

```
select id
from Contact
order by CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, Name
```